# How to download an Excel file from ASP.NET Web API in Angular application?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

The file downloads fine when I was returning it as a base64 string but now I have to change that from API and what to do in Angular 12 side in `ExportExcel()` where I am calling the below service:

```
this.apiService.downloadData(downloadData).subscribe(res => {
 console.log(res);
}
```

Note that the server creates the response like this:

```
public FileResult GetExcelFile([FromBody] DownloadData model)
{
    string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    string fileName = "authors.xlsx";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Student");
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]
       { 
           new DataColumn("Id"),
           new DataColumn("Cid"),
           new DataColumn("Restaurant"),
           new DataColumn("Date")
       });

    var recordingWasteData = _downloadExcelClientRepository.GetWasteData(model.start, model.end);

    foreach (var item in recordingWasteData)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(item.id, item.cid, item.restaurant, item.date);
    }

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        // Add DataTable in worksheet  
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(stream);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), contentType, fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

My api.service file is this:

```
public downloadData(req: DownloadData) {
    return this.apiService.post('api/Report/GetExcelFile', req);
}
```

I have a core service file which is called by this above api service file.

```
public post(path: string, body: object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
               .post(this.baseUrl + path, JSON.stringify(body), this.options)
               .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't see an actual question here. What's the problem you're facing? Are there any errors? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @PhilippMeissner Thanks for your reply but I am facing the problem in my angular code its not downloading the file as Excel now. So I wanted to know where to make change on Angular code or should I change the ASP.NET web API to return type?

Comment: just let the form do it's thing... you don't want the file returned back to Javascript.  Ex:<form ngNoForm method="post" action="{{exportURL}}" (submit)="setDownloadState();">

Comment: you'll probably want to use stream.Position = 0;  Then return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);

Comment: Hi @browsermator Its still not working with this stream.Position = 0;  I don't know what to do on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');
return this.http.get(apiurl, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' });
```

Comment: Hi @Jalpesh Vadgama I have already tried this as given code below but its not working `private httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/octet-stream'
  }),
  observe: 'response' as 'body',
  responseType: 'blob' as 'blob'
};` and this is where I am calling it `public post(path: string, body: object = {}): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient
    .post(this.baseUrl + path, JSON.stringify(body), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}`

Comment: What error you are getting? The one which I provided is different from what you pasted here

Comment: Hi @Jalpesh Vadgama This is what I am getting error while downloading Excel file https://pasteboard.co/0inHtG1KFbSQ.png

Comment: are you suing same code which I have given or any other because you using JSON to create excel file which will not work

Comment: Hi @Jalpesh Vadgama yes I am using the same code that you have given its still not working.